# Is the set of singular matrices negligible

Tags: linear-algebra, measure-theory

Consider the set $S$ of all singular matrices as a subset of $\mathbb{C}^{n^2}$ (or $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$) (if we consider complex matrices, or real matrices). 
Is $S$ negligible for the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{C}^{n^2}$ (or $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$)?  Intuitively this ought to be true since a "typical" matrix is nonsingular.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. The set of such matrices is the vanishing set of the determinant function $\det_n$, which is a polynomial. By [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/25586/102998), the vanishing set of any polynomial must have Lebesgue measure zero.