# Are the columns of a random Toeplitz Matrix linearly independent?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability-theory, toeplitz-matrices

Consider a [Toeplitz matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toeplitz_matrix) $T \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times p}$ with randomly independently generated entries and $n < p$. The entries of the Toeplitz matrix are generated by a continuous random variable.
Now, let's take $n$ columns $T_1, \dots , T_n$ of $T$.

Are $T_1, \dots, T_n$ linearly independent with probability 1 for any such selection $T_1, \dots , T_n$?

Comment: The linear dependence of $T_1, \dotsc, T_n$ is a polynomial condition in the entries of the matrix, so as long as the columns have distinct indices, then I think the set of Toeplitz matrices with those columns dependent should be a Lebesgue null set, since it's a proper (justify this bit!) subvariety of $\Bbb R^{n \times p}$. (eg see [this](https://mathoverflow.net/q/25513)). It's a similar argument to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3419233/473276).

Comment: I also believe that's the way to go: Prove that those linear conditions are satisfied only in a Lebesgue null set. And that's how you can easily prove that, for instance, a set of i.i.d. Gaussian vectors $x^{(1)}, \dots, x^{(p)}$ is linearly independent because the resulting linear system provides linear equations of the kind $x^{(p)} = \sum \alpha_i x^{(i)}$. A Toeplitz-System is a bit more difficult to break down into a System $x^{(p)\prime} = \sum \alpha_i^\prime x^{(i)\prime}$, where $x^{(p)\prime}$ is independent of the others. Perhaps there is an equivalent system in echelon form or so.

Comment: Hi Douglas. Can you follow the argument given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3419233/473276)? Do you see why it also applies to the set of singular $n \times n$ Toeplitz matrices? This basically answers your question, I believe. It's the vanishing set of a nonzero polynomial, so it must have measure zero.

Comment: Hi Izaak, that's a very elegant proof. Thank you so much. I provided the proof in an answer to this question.

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen But how could you prove that the determinant of $T_1, \dots, T_n$ is a non-zero polynomial? For instance, how can you prove that we don't get into failure cases such as in $A=[[a, b], [a, b]]$ with $\det(A)= ab - ab=0$?

Comment: Hi Douglas - apologies for the slow reply. I have to say it seems less obvious than I made it sound! I think I'd assumed there would be some obvious choice of values for the indeterminates for which the determinant is nonzero, but I can't see that right away. Nevertheless I think it's true, for example because "a matrix whose entries are indeterminates, such that each indeterminate appears at most once in each row and column has a nonzero determinant", which you can prove by looking at the definition of the determinant and using some sort of induction...

Comment: EG: pick any one of the indeterminates, $X$. Say $X$ appears $n$ times in the matrix. We'll argue that all terms in the determinant in which $X$ appears $n$ times do not cancel each other out. Indeed, these terms all come from the submatrix formed by deleting every row and column with an $X$ in (to be exact - the sum of these terms is $\pm X^n$ multiplied by the determinant of this submatrix). So by induction, those terms do not cancel each other out.

Answer (score 2):

We can prove this in 2 Steps:

1. Show that each $n \times n$ submatrix $T^\prime$ of $T$ is invertible.
2. From 1., it follows that each selection of $n$ columns must be linearly independent since they form a basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

*Proof:*

1. The determinant of every such submatrix $T^\prime$ is a polynomial $p(t_1, \dots, t_j)$, where $t_i$ are the diagonal entries. We know that every polynomial has a finite set of arguments $(t_1, \dots, t_j)$, such that $p(t_1, \dots, t_j)=0$*. Hence, if for all $i$: $t_i\sim \mathbb{P}_i$ for continuous distributions $\mathbb{P}_i$, then the zero-set of $p$ is a set with measure $0$. Therefore, with probability 1 it holds that $\det(T^\prime)=p(t_1, \dots , t_j)\neq 0$, and hence $T^\prime$ must be invertible.
2. As already explained at the beginning of the answer, we can now derive that the columns of $T^\prime$ form a basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$, and therefore are linearly independent with probability $1$.

*Note that $p\neq 0$.